# Why is this a continuity principle?

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, intuition, limsup-and-liminf, potential-theory

I am trying to understand the following theorem from Ransford's *Potential Theory in the Complex Plane* intuitively. Why exactly is it called a continuity principle? Can someone explain?

$p_{\mu}(z):= \int \log |z-w| d \mu (w), z \in \mathbb{C}$

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Write down the definition of continuous at a point for a regular function.

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't see the connection to the support

Comment: Could (b) mean: if the function is continuous in the support, it is continuous everywhere?